# iOS CoreBluetooth - Nothing happens when writing to characteristic for Zebra label printer

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, zebra-printers

I have been around all kinds of tutorials and help pages, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I have purchased a Zebra ZD421D label printer with bluetooth (ble), and i'm now trying to develop my own custom iOS app to print to it. I have gotten so far that I can see it in my app as peripheral. I can connect to it and I can get services and characteristics. But when using WriteValue for the characteristic, nothing happens. I have tried for all different characteristics I can find to see if I got the wrong one, but same result.

To see if I had done something wrong, i downloaded the LightBlue app, where peripherals and characteristics can be tested. But this won't send anything to the printer either. So I'm a bit confused. In LightBlue, i found the printer, connected to it, selected the peripheral, selected the characteristic, clicked on "write new value" and then clicked OK. But nothing happened at all.

I don't know if it can be some kind of configuration in the printer or something? I have looked in the Zebra printer setup app, but can't find anything that could sound like it could solve my problem.

Below is the swift code i'm using.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
    private var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    private var printerPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    @Published var peripheralNames: [String] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
    }
}

extension BluetoothViewModel: CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
            self.peripheralNames.append(peripheral.name ?? "Unnamed Device")
            //print("\(peripheral.name ?? "Unnamed Device") - \(peripheral.identifier) - \(RSSI)")
            
            if (peripheral.identifier.uuidString == "F9FC7DFB-F149-4F95-7CEF-D6596338D032") {
                centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
                self.printerPeripheral = peripheral
                self.printerPeripheral.delegate = self
                
                print("connecting to \(peripheral.name ?? "Unnamed Device")")
                centralManager?.stopScan()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Failed to connect to \(peripheral). (\(error!.localizedDescription))")
        
        //cleanup()
    }
    
    // The handler if we do connect succesfully
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == self.printerPeripheral {
            print("Connected to your printer")
            //peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID.init(string: peripheral.identifier.uuidString)])
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        }
    }
    
    // Handles discovery event
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("didDiscoverServices")
        if let services = peripheral.services {
            for service in services {
                print("Service - \(service.uuid.uuidString) - \(service.description)")
                //if service.uuid == CBUUID.init(string: peripheral.identifier.uuidString) {
                //if service.uuid == service.uuid {
                if service.uuid.uuidString.elementsEqual("38EB4A80-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B") {
                    print("Printer service found")
                    //Now kick off discovery of characteristics
                    //peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([CBUUID.init(string: service.uuid.uuidString)], for: service)
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
                    //return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Handling discovery of characteristics
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        print("didDiscoverCharactericsFor")
        if let characteristics = service.characteristics {
            print(characteristics.count)
            for characteristic in characteristics {
                print("Characteristic - \(characteristic.uuid)")
                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString.elementsEqual("38EB4A82-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B")) {
                    print("write")
                    //let bytesToPrint: [UInt8] = [27, 64, 10, 10, 10, 99, 105, 97, 111, 10, 10, 10]
                    //let bytesToPrint: [UInt8] = [27, 64, 10, 10]
                    //let data = Data(bytes: bytesToPrint)
                    //peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)

                    var data: String = "test"
                    let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    peripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
                    
                    
                    print("Value String===>\(valueString.debugDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Fejl \(error)")
          return
        }
         print("Message sent")
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var bluetoothViewModel = BluetoothViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(bluetoothViewModel.peripheralNames, id: \.self) { peripheral in
                Text(peripheral)
                    .navigationTitle("Peripherals")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Above code results in below output in the console:

```
connecting to D8J222507660
Connected to your printer
didDiscoverServices
Service - 180A - <CBService: 0x280250580, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>
Service - 38EB4A80-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B - <CBService: 0x2802502c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 38EB4A80-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B>
Printer service found
didDiscoverCharactericsFor
6
Characteristic - 38EB4A81-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B
Characteristic - 38EB4A82-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B
write
Value String===>6 bytes
Characteristic - 38EB4A83-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B
Characteristic - 38EB4A84-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B
Characteristic - 38EB4A87-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B
Characteristic - 38EB4A88-C570-11E3-9507-0002A5D5C51B
Message sent
```

Tried to write value to printer both from my own app but also from LightBlue. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am fighting the issue as well. In React Native Expo managed app I was able to connect to the printer (ZQ 521) and read it services and characteristics with react-native-ble-plx.

I found out uuids of service and characteristic to print to and I am able to send base64 encoded ZPL string to the printer and successfully print.

However I am having issues with longer ZPLs. Don't know if the write operation is length limited and I should do several write calls...

In your case, please check your printer settings, whether it is able to process what you are sending. I configured mine to read ZPL and at least for short ZPLs it is working correctly.